# How to get N bits from binary

Tags: erlang

I have some binary, how to get N bits from it ?
for example: <<2#101>> how to get first bit ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using binary pattern matching:

```erlang
1> Bin = <<2#101>>.
<<5>>
2> <<FirstBits:1, Rest/bitstring>> = Bin.
<<5>>
3> FirstBits.
0
4> Rest.
<<5:7>>
```

The expression `FirstBits:1` grabs the first bit. `Rest` is now 7 bits. You'll need to use `bitstring` as the type for any binary data as it will not be a multiple of 8 bits anymore (which the `binary` type enforces).

Looking at the bits individually we can see that `Rest` is now the last 7 bits of the original binary:

```erlang
5> bit_size(Bin).
8
6> [Bit || <<Bit:1>> <= Bin]. % Convert the binary to a "bit list"
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
7> bit_size(Rest).
7
8> [Bit || <<Bit:1>> <= Rest].
[0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
```

You can use any length to grab a fixed number of bits (e.g. `FirstBits:3` to grab the first three bits). The default type is `integer` if no type is specified. If you want a new binary you can use the type `bitstring`, like so `FirstBits:3/bitstring`.

```erlang
(> <<PrefixNum:3, _/bitstring>> = <<2#01010101>>.
<<"U">>
10> PrefixNum.
2
11> <<PrefixBit:3/bitstring, _/bitstring>> = <<2#01010101>>.
<<"U">>
12> PrefixBit.
<<2:3>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Erlang Bit Syntax explanation in the documentation, that should clarify things:

http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html

I wrote up a little example using ID3 tags when I started learning Erlang (not that I ever got far in that endeavor):

http://citizen428.net/archives/993

Comment: Thanks for your example with ID3 tags, it's usefull.

Comment: In function parse_id3(<<T:30/binary,Ar:30/binary,Al:30/binary,Y:4/binary,C:30/binary,G:1/binary>>) T:30 is element T size 30 bytes, but for example we can declare variable M = <<H:5,T:3>> where H is 5 bit and T is 3 bit. Where is the difference between bytes and bits in binary sintax?